# How to obtain R's scatterplot car formula and coefficients?

Tags: r, model, scatter-plot, mgcv, r-car

Is there a way to gain the equations and coefficients when using the R's car package of both the smoothing and regression (line) model?

```
scatterplot(prestige ~ income, data=Prestige)
scatterplot(prestige ~ income, data=Prestige, smoother=gamLine)
```

(the gamLine argument requiring the mgcv package)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, you can see the info by

```
summary(lm(prestige ~ income, data = Prestige))
```

In the 2nd case, something similar will likely apply but I don't know that package or smoothing method. It's surely not as simple as a linear fit.  Take a look at `?mgcv-FAQ`.